# I want to run an air aplication on my computer and stream it through a website. Is this possible?

Tags: flash, air, web, exe

I have created an air application that uses files on my computer and dose not need any others. I was wondering if it would be possible for me to run instances of this and have them streamed through a website. Creating a new instance of every new person on the site.

Comment: would you mind explaining more about your question???

Comment: MGol I created a eReader using air because of the Files class which is only available in air. However I realise when I published it that it created an adobe exe so cannot be embedded in a website (at Least I don't think so). I would like a way for this to function like a normal swf from the users point of view.

Comment: most native application running functions of air are not supported in normal as3 in web application. so if you want to use it as a web application you need to use some middleware like asp.net or php or javascript to do those functions and communicate with swf file

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. Adobe AIR cannot be run through the web and, for security reasons, web-based Flash applications do not have the type of access to files that `File` provides.

Moreover, AIR apps are pretty much completely sandboxed. AIR has little-to-no access to other applications and other applications have little-to-no access to AIR (even less than web-based SWFs, I believe).

You either have to allow the user to choose the file to load themselves (using `FileReference` in a web-based SWF) or forget the browser entirely and allow your application to run as an actual application on Windows/Mac (you can compile to a .air file which will run on both, if the user has Adobe AIR installed on the machine).